# Can't run new project in win64 mode, but win32 mode works fine

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I have recently reformatted my computer running Windows 8.1 and re-installed Delphi XE6 which was working fine prior to formatting the computer. Whenever i open up a new project and hit F9 (Windows 64 as target platform) i receive the following error:

`Debugger Assertion Failure: "lastErr == WSAEINTR" in ..\win32src\wmcipc.cpp at line 294`

`Fatal error starting debugger kernel: 'Invalid debugger request'. Please save your work and restart RAD Studio XE6`

I downloaded XE7 trial and ran into the same problem. I have done some google search but cannot find a resolution.

I guess there is some user access problem or a program blocking the debugger?

Comment: You should contact the vendor and ask for support

Comment: Did you install 32 bit or 64 bit version of Windows 8.1? Because if you perhaps installed 32 bit version of Windows you won't be able to compile or run any 64 bit application.

Comment: Definitely using 64 bit windows

Comment: Debugging is kind of important but it does compile fine with Ctrl+Shift+F9 but i am just curious, why was it working prior to reformatting my computer.

Comment: @Silver You can compile 64bit apps on 32bit Windows, the compiler is still 32bit itself. But of course you can not run or debug the output.

Comment: You need to talk to the vendor

Comment: Fresh installed Windows 8.1, now it works fine. I guess something was blocking the debugger? Going to reinstall everything one by one and find out what was blocking it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

This Question was answered here for the case of malware interfering with your winsock stack:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=712725 (dead link, here is a [snapshot from December 8th, 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20161208001235/https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=712725)) [1]

"Open a command prompt as Administrator, and run"

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Please note that the original post also states:

> **This will remove any other winsock LSPs that you have, so you will need to re-install them. (firewalls, security software, etc.)**

---

[1]: *Full text of the original post to prevent link rot making it unavailable again (link to the migrated Embarcadero issue and formatting added by me)*:

> There was something about this that was closed in [QC#104007](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12208), however I wasn't able to find any particular cures listed, but I did manage to find a method of making the debugger work again. This was caused (on my system) by a particularly obnoxious piece of malware that piggyback installed itself. Even after removing the malware, there was still an additional piece of software in the winsock stack, which prevents the 64-bit debugger from starting up. the file `LavasoftTcpService64.dll` is supposedly perfectly reputable, however I have never installed ad-aware, so it has no business being on my computer. It cannot be easily removed, as doing so will give you wonderful fun with system restore and startup repair. (And on my system, any system restore points which didn't have lavasoft in them were dysfunctional).
>
> However, windows does give a nice tool which can remove it and make your debugger work again.
> Open a command prompt as Administrator, and run
>
> `netsh winsock reset`
> After rebooting, your 64-bit debugger should work again.
>
> This will remove any other winsock LSPs that you have, so you will need to re-install them. (firewalls, security software, etc.)

Comment: This should marked as answer. This resolved "debugger kernel has stopped working" and related "unable create process" errors for me.

Comment: Also link is broken, so it would be good to elaborate why this error happens

Comment: Agree with VitalyG. This is the correct answer.